# Android JSON to Kotlin Class with ViewHolder

Tags: android, kotlin

I have a problem when using data class that generated by the [JSONToKotlinClass](https://plugins.jetbrains.com/plugin/9960-json-to-kotlin-class-jsontokotlinclass-) extension from Android Studio.

So i converted [this](https://jsonplaceholder.typicode.com/users) JSON to data class in kotlin, The generated classes are `UserDataClass`, `UserDataClassItem`, `Geo`, `Company` and `Address`.

This is what `UserDataClass` looks like :

```
package com.example.kotlinretrofitexample

class UserDataClass : ArrayList<UserDataClassItem>()
```

And this is what `UserDataClassItem` looks like :

```
package com.example.kotlinretrofitexample

import com.google.gson.annotations.SerializedName

data class UserDataClassItem(
    @SerializedName("id")
    var id: Int,
    @SerializedName("name")
    var name: String,
    @SerializedName("username")
    var username: String,
    @SerializedName("email")
    var email: String,
    @SerializedName("address")
    var address: Address,
    @SerializedName("phone")
    var phone: String,
    @SerializedName("website")
    var website: String,
    @SerializedName("company")
    var company: Company
)
```

So what i want to do is show these data with RecyclerView. Here's the Adapter i created :

```
class UserAdapter(private val data: List<UserDataClass>?) : RecyclerView.Adapter<UserAdapter.MyHolder>(){

override fun onCreateViewHolder(parent: ViewGroup, viewType: Int): MyHolder {
    val v = LayoutInflater.from(parent.context).inflate(R.layout.item_user, parent, false)
    return MyHolder(v)
}

override fun getItemCount(): Int = data?.size ?: 0

override fun onBindViewHolder(holder: MyHolder, position: Int) {
    holder.bind(data?.get(position))
}

class MyHolder(itemView: View) : RecyclerView.ViewHolder(itemView) {
    fun bind(get: UserDataClass?) {
        itemView.nama.text = get?.name
        itemView.email.text = get?.email
        itemView.notelp.text = get?.phone
        val address = "${get?.address?.street}, ${get?.address?.city}, ${get?.address?.suite}, ${get?.address?.zipcode}"
        itemView.alamat.text = address
    }
}

}
```

When Built, the error message returned :

`Unresolved reference. None of the following candidates is applicable because of receiver type mismatch:`

`Unresolved reference : name`

`Unresolved reference : phone`

`Unresolved reference : address`

Did i miss something ?? If there are things unclear, let me know!

***Edit*** :

This is for the `Address` class :

```
data class Address(
    @SerializedName("street")
    var street: String,
    @SerializedName("suite")
    var suite: String,
    @SerializedName("city")
    var city: String,
    @SerializedName("zipcode")
    var zipcode: String,
    @SerializedName("geo")
    var geo: Geo
)
```

This is for the `Company Class` :

```
data class Company(
    @SerializedName("name")
    var name: String,
    @SerializedName("catchPhrase")
    var catchPhrase: String,
    @SerializedName("bs")
    var bs: String
)
```

And this is for the `Geo` class:

```
data class Geo(
    @SerializedName("lat")
    var lat: String,
    @SerializedName("lng")
    var lng: String
)
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I believe you are getting `UserDataClassItem`  instead of `UserDataClass`

so pass the `UserDataClassItem` to your adapter class in constructor.

```
class UserAdapter(private val data: List< UserDataClassItem >?) : RecyclerView.Adapter<UserAdapter.MyHolder>(){

 //change accordingly

}
```